# Literature on Sabermetrics in baseball

Tags: statistics, reference-request, soft-question, stochastic-processes

For my bachelor's thesis, I would like to study the use of Sabermetrics in baseball.

I was fascinated by the book 'Moneyball: The Art of Winning an Unfair Game' by Michael Lewis, and to me, it seemed a great opportunity to show the impact of the use of mathematics in modern culture. The use of statistics to scout players based on their statistical performances, rather than 'subjective' attributes, like hitting percentage and sprint speed, really struck me.

Now, I have a problem: there is not a lot of literature available about this phenomenon, and from the available literature, most of it is fairly easy. It makes for a fun read, but it will not suffice as literature for my thesis.

I have about two articles that might work, but I need more scientific literature to complete my thesis. I was looking for the use of stochastics in sabermetrics, but that did not yield a lot of results.

Hope anyone can help me out.

Comment: From the baseball side, you might start with http://fangraphs.com, which has a number of these advanced statistics and a reasonable amount of discussion of the motivations behind them - the fundamental concept that keeps recurring is to divorce _actions_ from _results_, because the former have predictability and the latter don't - for instance, on-base percentage has better year-over-year correlations than batting average, but line-drive percentage is even better, whereas the number of LDs that fall for hits is somewhat 'random' for any given player.

Answer (score 0):

[arXiv.org](http://arxiv.org) might be a nice place to start. I searched for the term "baseball" in two ways. I used the [arXiv search function](http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all%3a+baseball/0/1/0/all/0/1). And I also used [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&ei=0rqQU9f5MNDJsQTu24KIAg&ved=0CBcQ1S4#q=baseball%20arxiv). Here are three interesting looking articles:

(1) [Bayesball: A Bayesian hierarchical model for evaluating fielding in major league baseball](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.4317)

(2) [openWAR: An Open Source System for Evaluating Overall Player Performance in Major League Baseball](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7158)

(3) [Trouble With The Curve: Improving MLB Pitch Classification](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1756)